# ‘Unless’ Firestore query?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am make chat app. I have many user group. For example Group A, Group B, Group C. If user is Group A he can connect with other user in Group A.

So for give list of available user in Group A I have simple query:

```
.where(otherUserGroup, isEqualTo: currentUserGroup)
```

But now I want allow only some user in Group A see other user in Group A. For example if user is in location NY he is invisible to most user and only visible to other user who also have location NY. BUT I still want all user in NY be able to see all other user in Group A.

So I want run query like this (pseudocode):

```
.where(otherUserGroup, isEqualTo: currentUserGroup)
BUT do not return user document where otherUserLocation, isEqualTo: [List of location in Firestore collection (for example NY)]
UNLESS otherUserLocation, isEqualTo: currentUserLocation
```

How to make this query?

Answer (score 1):

The only OR-like conditions that Firestore supports are `in` and `array-contains-any`, which check a single field for a bunch of given values. Doing any sort of OR condition across multiple fields is not possible with Cloud Firestore at the moment.

As far as I can see there is no way to do your complex OR condition in a single query.

You'll have to fire a separate query for each, and then merge the results in your application code.